# IIS: Regex Including Dot/Period

Tags: regex, iis, iis-7.5

I have the following rules. The second works but the first doesn't seem to to fire. For example, URL in question for the first rule is `index.cfm?section=artists.az&id=22707` and for the 2nd rule which works, the URL is `index.cfm?section=artists&id=22707`

```
<rule name="Artists: AZ" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index\.cfm$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^section=artists\.az&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="artist.php?id={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="Artists: index.cfm" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index\.cfm$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^section=artists&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="artist.php?id={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

ANy ideas?

Comment: Does it mean you want to combine them? Like [`pattern="^section=artists(?:\.az)?&amp;id=([^=&amp;]+)$"`](https://regex101.com/r/eM3qH6/1)?

Comment: Rules were fine - just needed to restart IIS!

Comment: Then please consider removing the question.

Comment: Well, you have an option to answer yourself, but I do not know what value this will have for future visitors.